# OutOfMemory Exception when loading lots of Images from Isolated storage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

**EDIT:** I keep getting OutOfMemoryException was unhandled, 
I think it's how I am saving the image to isolated storage ,I think this is where I can solve my problem how do I reduce the size of the image before I save it?  (added code where I save Image)

I am opening images from Isolated storage sometimes over 100 images and I want to loop over them images but I get a `OutOfMemory Exception` when there is around 100 to 150 images loaded in to a storyboard.  How can I handle this exception, I have already brought down the resolution of the images.  How can I handle this exception and stop my app from crashing?

I get the exception at this line here

`image.SetSource(isStoreTwo.OpenFile(projectFolder + "\\MyImage" + i + ".jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));//images from isolated storage`

here's my code

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        IsolatedStorageFile isStoreTwo = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();



        try
        {
            storyboard = new Storyboard
            {
                //RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
            };

            var animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, projectImage);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Source"));


            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            for (int i = 1; i <= savedCounter; i++)
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

                image.SetSource(isStoreTwo.OpenFile(projectFolder + "\\MyImage" + i + ".jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));//images from isolated storage

                var keyframe = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                {

                    KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100 * i)),
                    Value = image
                };

                animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyframe);
            }
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException exc)
        {

            //throw;

        }



        Resources.Add("ProjectStoryBoard", storyboard);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

> **EDIT**  This is how I am saving the image to Isolated storage, I think this is where I can solve my problem, How do I reduce the size of the image when saving it to isolated storage?

```
    void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
    {

        string fileName = folderName+"\\MyImage" + savedCounter + ".jpg";

        try
        {  

            // Save picture to the library camera roll.
            //library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ImageStream);



            // Set the position of the stream back to start
            e.ImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Save picture as JPEG to isolated storage.
            using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {

                    // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
                    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead = -1;

                    // Copy the image to isolated storage. 
                    while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                }

            }




        }
        finally
        {
            // Close image stream
            e.ImageStream.Close();
        }

    }
```

I would appreciate if you could help me thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the OutOfMemory Exception because you are storing all the images in memory at the same time in order to create your StoryBoard. I don't think you will be able to overcome the uncompressed bitmap size that the images require to be displayed on screen.

So to get past this we must think about your goal rather than trying to fix the error. If your goal is to show a new image in sequence every X ms then you have a few options.

1. Keep using StoryBoards but chain them using the OnCompleted event. This way you don't have to create them all at once but can just generate the next few. It might not be fast enough though if you're changing images every 100ms.
2. Use CompositionTarget.Rendering as mentioned in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125496/269608). This would probably take the least amount of memory if you just preload the next one (as opposed to having them all preloaded as your current solution does). You'd need to manually check the elapsed time though.
3. Rethink what you're doing. If you state what you are going after people might have more alternatives.

Comment: Agreed. You shouldn't have to load 100 pictures at once. Load only those you need to display, and you can preload a few ones if you have a latency issue.

Comment: Hi Austin what I am trying to create is a Time Lapse Photography app that takes a photo every second or every few seconds for a certain amount of time so I would like if the time lapse could go on for longer than 3 minutes hence lots of images to load, I have compressed the images but they aren't great quality.  I will give your suggestions a go thanks.

Comment: @M_K Ok, let me know how it goes. Another option might be to use a timer, like a DispatcherTimer to change the image. That might be simpler than chaining StoryBoards or using CompositionTarget.Rendering . Here is a very similar example using that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429728/changing-image-in-a-wpf-image-from-an-image-sequence-in-the-hard-drive-makes-the

Comment: @AustinThompson you helped me greatly I've dumped the storyboard and gone with the thread, the memory seems to be grand for now, will have to do some tests with a great deal of photo's. Really appreciate your help, I will award you the bounty if all goes well.  

On a side note is the Visual Studio Marketplace Testkit reliable, is this the test kit that the app hub use to certify?

Comment: @M_K Glad to help. As for the Testkit, in my experience the automated tests have definitely caught a few things before that saved me from having to resubmit. But the manual ones are where you will get variance from tester to tester. Certainly worth doing and then at least glancing at the manual tests.

Comment: Yes I've done the automated one, but the monitored test is a bit strange saying it took my app 83 seconds to open when it opened straight away, I tried adding the bounty to your answer there but apparently it's awarded automatically afterwards, I'm not sure how it works, but you should receive it, am I right?

Comment: Yep, I have it. Thanks :)  .. it's odd about the 83 seconds though. I'll check mine when I go to submit my next update.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't matter how large your images are on disk because when you load them into memory they're going to be uncompressed. The memory required for the image will be approximately `(stride * height)`. `stride` is `width * bitsPerPixel)/8`, and then rounded up to the next multiple of 4 bytes. So an image that's 1024x768 and 24 bits per pixel will take up about 2.25 MB.

You should figure out how large your images are, uncompressed, and use that number to determine the memory requirements.

Comment: My images are coming out 640x480, bit depth 24, so that's not even 1mb, but I am opening isolated storage over a 100 times.

Comment: A 640x480 image at 24 bits per pixel is right at 900 kilobytes. 100 of those will give you 87 megabytes. Minimum. There's going to be some other overhead, as well. Do you know how many images are added before you get the out of memory exception?

Comment: Yes I have just checked the counter is 107 on the three times I have tested it

Comment: Uncompressed images are more likely to be stored in 32 bit per pixel format. In that case 107 images would take >125MB. What does task manages says about memory used by the process?

Comment: I don't know how to use the task manager, I think if I reduce the size of the images to 100kb or something then it could stop running out of memory. How can I reduce the size of the images when I save them.  I have added code above.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the edit at the top of your post, try [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/).  There's a NuGet package, and a [HanselBlog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx) episode on it.  Obviously , this is Asp.Net based, but I'm sure you could butcher it to work in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Tackling these kind of problems at design layer usually works better.

Making application smart about the running environment via some configurations makes your application more robust. For example you can define some variables like image size, image count, image quality... based on available memory and set these variables at run-time in your App. So your application always works; fast on high memory machines and slow on low memory ones; but never crash. (Don't believe working in managed environment means no worry about the environment... Design always matters)

Also there are some known design patterns like [Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) you can benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, an image (1024x768) has at least a memsize of 3 mb (argb)

Don't know how ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames works internal. Maybe you can force the gc by destroying the instances of BitmapImage (and KeyFrames) without loss of its data in the animation.
(not possible, see comments!)

Comment: Hi how can I use the garbage collector?

Comment: @ck0ne You're calculation is inaccurate, many things determine the size of a .jpg picture. OP, can you change the file format to .png on save (or on a pre-process)? That *usually* yields smaller pictures.

Comment: There is no difference between both formats when I explored the isolated storage both were around 5.73 KB in size

Comment: just image.finalize() at end of the iterationblock. @Pedro: If you're sure, ok! But the internal representation is only one in BitmapImage, whether it is created from bmp, png or jpg. And in case of saving the BitmapImage-content as jpg-data, each action on any pixels would need de-/encoding the data.

Comment: `image.finalize()` gives me an error? No extension method finalize()

Comment: ^^^**just image.finalize() at end of the iterationblock.**  Your comment above

Comment: Right, as java-programmer i write methods lowercase. In WP7 it seems to be "image. **F** inalize()". Sorry, if that was the reason.

Comment: I still get an error  with  `Cannot access protected member 'object.~Object()' via a qualifier of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage'; the qualifier must be of type 'myApp.ProjectView' (or derived from it)`

Comment: Also right, its protected. Before trying to override/redirected call from a derived class. Lets try to move the initialization out of the iteration and only do SetSource on the same instance in the for-loop.

Comment: I need to keep the instance of the bitmap there because it just loads the last image otherwise

Comment: Ok, then even the forced gc isn't possible.

Comment: I keep getting OutOfMemoryException was unhandled on this loop, but I am handling it with a try and catching it with OutOfMemoryException. Do you know why it isnt getting handled I'm trying to catch it and display error in a message box?

Comment: OutOfMemoryException should be one of the critical exceptions which will lead to an immediate exit. Even if you handle the exception you would need more memory to allocate for the errormessage and so on ... but you could readout the current size of your app and abort the iteration before reaching this much

Comment: How can I reduce the size of the images to 100kb or around that so I the phone does not run out of memory?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about windows phone in particular, but in .net winforms, you need to use a separate thread when doing a long-running task.  Are you using a BackgroundWorker or equivalent?  The [finalizer thread can become blocked](http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/06/22/blocked-finalizer-thread/), which will prevent the resources for the images from being disposed. Using a separate thread from the UI thread will allow will allow the Dispose method to be run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of your comments, you are building a Time Lapse app. Commercial time-lapse apps for WP7 compress the images to video, not stills.  e.g. [Time Lapse Pro](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-app-review-timelapse-pro)

The whole point of video playback is to reduce similar, or time-related, images to highly compressed stream *that do not require massive amounts of memory to play back*.

If you can add the ability to encode to video, in your app, you will avoid the problem of trying to emulate a video player (using 100s of single full-resolution frames as a flick-book).

*Processing the images into video server-side may be another option (but not as friendly as in-camera).*

Comment: Is this app compressing the images into video?? because I don't think it does, when you read the comments in that link you posted users are asking why you can't save as video and share to Facebook. I was trying to find a way to do this and could not find a way, that is why I have to do it this way for the time being.  Do you know of a way to compress the images to video?

Comment: They are likely compressing using a custom library as you can't do really fast compression in C# (Just not enough grunt). Start looking for a video compression/playback library written in C# the you can use. You don't care about the codec unless you want to share the file. The alternative (which opens up lots of sharing options) is to send the files to your server and create the video there using one of many compression libraries. The basic problem with your single-frame approach is the sheer weight of data you are shifting/storing. You need to hold less data in memory at any given time on WP7