# wpf video or image array seek animation

Tags: wpf, video, video-codecs

I'm about to build a application where I need a highdef video ( 3072 x 768 ) to play either forward or backward between application states ( to fake 3d ) , coming form flash/air I know that its possible to animate the seek/playback scrubber with a tween animation.

So want to know howto get the best preformance playing prerendered images or video between the states in WPF. If anyone have any experience doing this please let me know.

Options are : 
1) do somekind of image sequence of the images between the states ( think this is very performance heavy ).

2) animate the seek / scrubber ( again concerned about preformance)

3) create 2 movies for each state ( so I dont need the backward seek animation )
is it possible to load the movies so they dont flicker when started or stoped.

Any inputs are appreciated : 
- best codecs for stuff like this etc.

cheers

---

I went with the image sequence solution . Link below:
[Changing Image in a WPF Image from an image sequence in the hard drive makes the Image turn pitch black and less responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429728/changing-image-in-a-wpf-image-from-an-image-sequence-in-the-hard-drive-makes-the)

Comment: I don't understand? you need to play video either forward or backward?

Comment: when you go into a state the video plays forward - when you exit back to a previous state or view you can play it backwards. the effect is something like this http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=67 . Just highdef fullscreen bg video with menus on top. 
But what I'm after is more the best preformance for displaying video in WPF. My application is a tour through a house where the playhead stops sometimes and displays menus. You can move back and fourth between locations. hope this clarifies it.

Comment: I went with the image sequence solution from [here][1] : 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429728/changing-image-in-a-wpf-image-from-an-image-sequence-in-the-hard-drive-makes-the